# Convex hull and optimal solutions

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-programming, convex-hulls

Consider the LP problem:

$max$ $3x_1 + 2x_2+x_3$

$s.t$ $3x_1 + 4x_2 + x_3 ≤ 6 $

$2x_1+x_2 + 3x_3 ≤ 5 $

$x_1,x_2,x_3 ≥0$

I have solved the problem and found that the optimal value is 6 at $x=(2,0,0)$.

Now I have to find two points $x_1$ and $x_2$ so that the set of optimal solutions of the problem above can be written as $conv(x_1,x_2)$. How do I solve this?

I also have all the extreme points of the feasible region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $3x_1+2x_2+x_3=6$, plug that into the first inequality to derive $2x_2\leq 0$ implying $x_2=0$
using the first equation
$$3x_1+x_3=6$$
we derive at
$$x_3=6-3x_1$$

now intersect this with the feasible region (second inequality) and you should be done by using the boundary values of the set of solutions (note that these values are $\subset \mathbb{R}^3$) because the relationship is linear

Comment: I got that $x_1$=$13/7$ and $x_3$=$3/7$, which is also one of the extreme points. But why do we choose that $x_2 = 0$. Does this mean that the values are $x_1$=$13/7$ and $x_2=0$ that give $
conv(x_1,x_2)$?

Comment: The values $x_1,x_2,x_3$ in the equations are coordinates, the vectors for the conv hull are different $\mathbb{R}^3$ vectors, where the second component $x_2$ is zero, it is bad notation in the task I guess, so for example $x_1=(2,0,0)$

Comment: So better formulation is find vecors $v_1, v_2 \in\mathbb{R}^3$ such that all solutions are in $conv(v_1,v_2)$

Comment: So $v_1=(13/7,0,3/7)$ ; $v_2=(2,0,0)$

Comment: It makes sense now, I was confused by the notation.